# Replacing <a>-tag linktext with different text

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I try to map the following html (it´s a small fce)..

```
<div>
    <div data-hero="1">
        <h1>
            <!-- Headline -->
        </h1>
        <p>
            <!-- Small Text -->
        </p>
        <p>
            <a>
                <span><!-- Button Text --></span>
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Mapping is ok... But when i map the `<span>` i get a `No content found div[1] div[1] p[2] a[1] span[1]` error. The `<a>`-Tag is mapped `outter` so it should work..

What I try to achieve: Set a Text that is displayed in the `<a>`-tag, instead of the link target itself.

It´s a TYPO3 4.7 using the latest TemplaVoilà.

Why is that? Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

@biesior suggested this is not possible - so no i wrap a `<span>` into the `<a>`-tag via Typoscript.

Is there a chance to display a certain fields content in this `<span>` - speak: replacing the linktext, so that i can have a `Click here for more ...` instead of `pageXY`?

Btw: I use a `linkfield` and not the Rich-Text-Editor for setting the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can not map any element nested in previously mapped element.

The fastest solution is mapping the `A` tag, and wrapping inserted text with `<span>|</span>` with TypoScript.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to have a fields content being filled into the a tag, or span, like `Check this out...` instead of `page4` - of course individually for every used element?