# TYPO3 with TemplaVoila - permission issue

Tags: php, typo3

I keep getting this error when I as an admin user try to create any content:

> "Sorry, you didn't have proper permissions to perform this change"

It seems to be some kind of a permission bug on TemplaVoila. Any ideas how to resolve it?

I'm using `TYPO3 4.7.5` and `TempleVoila 1.7.0`

Comment: Is your error similar to the one I encounter? http://stackoverflow.com/q/13083989/1064416

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the following code in the sql database: `ALTER TABLE pages ADD t3ver_swapmode tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0'` as per mentioned on [this site](http://www.codeterrorizer.com/typoscript/typo3-4-7-templavoila-templavoila-sorry-you-didnt-have-proper-permissions-to-perform-this-change).